# Load bundles concurrently instead of consecutively

Tags: performance, browser, aurelia, systemjs

We are using SystemJS to load two bundles: `aurelia.js` and `app-build.js`. SystemJs is loading them one after the other. How can we ask SystemJs to load them concurrently?

[image: Two xhr requests, one after the other.]

Our config.js, with details omitted for clarity, looks like this:

```
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "none",
  paths: {
    // omitted
  },
  meta: {
    // omitted
  },
  map: {
    // omitted
  },
  bundles: {
    "app-build.js": [
      "about.html!github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.3.js",
      "about.js",
      "admin.html!github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.3.js",
      "admin.js",
       // et cetera
    ],
    "aurelia.js": [
      "github:HubSpot/tether@1.3.2.js",
      "github:HubSpot/tether@1.3.2/js/tether.js",
      "github:Leaflet/Leaflet@0.7.7.js",
      "github:Leaflet/Leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet-src.js",
      // et cetera
    ]
  },
  depCache: {
    // omitted
  }
});
```

Comment: How are they loaded? Are you certain that `app-build` is workable when `aurelia` isn't loaded?

Comment: @estus Good question! `app-build` does depend on `aurelia`. It is not workable without it. I wonder... can we load `app-build` concurrently with its dependency?

Comment: @estus What do you mean by, "How are they loaded?" The answer that comes to mind is that SystemJs loads them. What details are you requesting?

Comment: Please, post the code that loads these packages. `System.config(...)` itself doesn't load anything. If `app-build` contains the code that starts the app, then no, you can't load them concurrently, because `app-build` will be executed after loading, and `aurelia` should be already loaded at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `config.js` tells the SystemJS loader in which bundle each module is located. SystemJS then lazy loads bundles as modules are needed. The reason you're seeing the above is that the dependency hierarchy is linear. Your `index.html` probably has a line like this:

```
  System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
```

So SystemJS looks for the 'aurelia-bootstrapper' model and loads the bundle that requires it. The bootstrapper than starts by loading your `main.js` or `app.js` file depending on your configuration.

**The best solution**

Do **not** separate your bundles. If you are bundling, you're likely GZipping as well, as these are both standard for a production environment and should always occur together. GZip will achieve higher compression ratios if you bundle all of your files into a single file. There's very little reason to separate your bundles, unless you didn't create the bundle yourself.

**The other solution**

Add a manual import of your other bundle with the 'aurelia-bootstrapper' import in your `index.html`.

```
<script>
  System.import('my-module/main');
  System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
</script>
```